# Upsert failed.INVALID_ID_FIELD, record id cannot be empty key: []

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension, standardcontroller, standardsetcontroller

I'm a beginner developer and I'm building a custom NEW contract button. I'm having issues getting the contract to insert/upsert and I think it has something to do with having a standardsetcontroller in my code. The problem is without it (and recordsetvar), it doesn't allow me to select the visualforce page when creating the list view button.

Error Message

> Upsert failed. First exception on row 0 with id 000000000000000; first error: INVALID_ID_FIELD, record id cannot be empty key: []
> Error is in expression '{!saveForm}' in component apex:commandButton in page societycontractrequestform: Class.SocietyContractRequest.saveForm: line 65, column 1

Controller Extension

```
public with sharing class SocietyContractRequest{
        
    public Contract Contract {get;set;}    
          
    public SocietyContractRequest(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        this.contract = (contract)controller.getRecord();
    }
    
    public SocietyContractRequest(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller){
        this.contract = (contract)controller.getRecord();
    }
    
    //Save page
    public PageReference saveForm(){
        system.debug('Saving Contract...');
        upsert Contract;
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + contract.Id);
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
       }
       
    //Cancel and return to the Contract List View
    public PageReference cancelPage(){
        return new ApexPages.Action('{!List}').invoke();
    }
}
```

Visualforce Page

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Contract" extensions="SocietyContractRequest" recordSetVar="sobjects">
    <Script>
        function setFocusOnLoad() {}
    </Script>    
      <apex:form >        
        <apex:commandButton action="{!saveForm}" value="Save Contract" />        
        <apex:commandButton action="{!cancelPage}" value="Cancel" immediate="true" />                
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE Justin -- there's too much code here that is irrelevant to your issue - you'll get more help if you use [edit] and strip away all the bits that don;t get at the root of the issue; e.g. we don;t need to see all these fields on Contract

Comment: Thanks for the advice @cropredy I've stripped away what I thought I could. I originally thought the whole picture is best, but simplifying makes sense.

Comment: do we need two SocietyContractRequest constructor? how about if you remove public SocietyContractRequest(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller)? StandardSetController is for multiple record

Comment: The problem is if I remove the StandardSetController, I can no longer have recordsetvar on my Visualforce page which is a requirement when creating a list button. All I want is a custom new list button to create a single contract record at a time (without having to override the standard new button)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was creating the list button with the required recordsetvar and StandardSetController... then removing the recordsetvar and changing to using a StandardController after the list button is created. Strange workaround, but it worked.